# Callback function inside class

Tags: c++, class, function, callback

I am trying to create a window container for sfml windows. If you are not familiar with sfml, a sfml window is a class which is non-copyable so cannot be put inside a std::vector for example.

I've done most of the work, but I am now trying to implement some sort of callback function which will do the open-gl drawing work before window.Display() is called to update the window.

I cannot get my head around the syntax of a callback function (either c or c++ version). Would someone be willing to explain an example to me?

Even better, would someone be willing to explain an example of how to implement a callback function in a class, so that a function (which the user defines) can be passed into a function of the class which will remember what that function was so it can be called by the class later.

To make that above sentence clearer: I think there are three things I need:

1): A function which the user defines, for example:

```
void doDrawing(){
    // do some open gl stuff
}
```

2:) A function inside a class which takes the argument of the above, user defined function:

```
void setDisplayFunc( ?argument of a function? argument ){
    function_pointer pointer = argument;
}
```

I have no idea what the type of 'argument' should be, or what 'function_pointer' has to be... I think this is where I am most stuck!

3:) A way in which the class can call the function which was assigned above.

```
// Do the function which is pointed at by pointer, which is of the type 'function_pointer' ... Whatever function_pointer happens to be!
```

If anyone has used glut before, then I guess I am trying to implement the glut callback functions which look like:

```
void someDisplayFunction(){
    // do open gl stuff
}

glutDisplayFunc( someDisplayFunction );
```

The above function takes the argument of a user-defined function and then does it when we call 'glutPostRedisplay' ...

I hope this makes sense, I have tried to include as much information as I can to help. Any help is appreciated. (:

Comment: how is this 'inside a class" related ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a function pointer. In your case:

```
typedef void (*function_pointer)();
```

With that you can write:

```
void setDisplayFunc(function_pointer argument){
    function_pointer pointer = argument;
}
```

To call it you simply do:

```
pointer();
```

Comment: Oh wow, wonderful thank you so much. I will start trying to implement this.

Comment: What does typedef void (*function_pointer)(); do? Does it declare a void pointer which the complier knows points to a function due to the extra parentheses at the end?

Comment: It declares a function pointer type. The parenthesis is part of the function declaration. You can add parameters there. The void is simply the return type of the function. For example, the type of a pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning a `bool` would be: `typedef bool (*function_pointer)(int);`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C++11, you could use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

```
void setDisplayFunc(const std::function<void()>& function) {
    function(); // call the function
}
```

It is in `<functional>` I believe, so remember to `#include <functional>`.

I also always forget the C-style syntax of function pointers, so I'm a big fan of using the STL in these kind of situations. You manage it like you would use any other object, and it is close to higher level languages such as C# (for passing functions, I mean).

If you are not using C++11 for your project, then you are stuck with the old syntax. See the other answers to see how to use it.

If you want to use it later however, take a look at the [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for the syntax with functions taking parameters, passing default parameters, etc. You might find it useful for further use.

Comment: I am using C++ 11 (or at least I can force code::blocks to use it).

What are the advantages of using stl over the traditional c style?

Comment: IMHO, I find it much more readable. You use it just like you would be using an object or an STL container. The STL has a lot to offer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to pass a pointer to a function, or a function pointer around.

```
typedef void (*function_pointer)();
```

Try this for the type of the `argument`. You can actually look at how glut does it by taking a look at its header.